# Orange juice preservation by chemical presevatives

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, food-preservation, fruit, juice

How much Sodium Benzoate should I add to preserve 200ml of Orange juice?

Answer (score 3):

From [NCBI](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29051632/) *(National Center for Biotechnology Information)*:

> **Sodium benzoate (0.4 g)** was added to **400 mL orange juice**.

So 200 ml of orange juice, being half the amount of 400 ml, may need **0.2 g of sodium benzoate**, which is half of 0.4 g.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_benzoate#Preservative), the [FDA](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/cfrsearch.cfm?fr=184.1733) (food&drug administration) allow up to 0.1% per weight.

"Concentration as a food preservative is limited by the FDA in the U.S. to 0.1% by weight"

So, m maximum of 0.1% per weight of the weight of your 200ml of orange juice.

Let's say 200ml of juice is at least 200g (more or less equivalent to water), you'd need to add **at most 0.2g** of Sodium Benzoate.

Comment: The information you found is a safety limit. It does not in any way say how much it should be actually used, and whether it is even a suitable preservative for orange juice specifically.

Comment: To be fair to Max, the original text of the question was "how much CAN I add" so he answered the text of the question, even if not the intent.